# Sharing Mysql Workbench configuration among multiple machines

Tags: mysql, configuration, share

Suppose I have many employees who connect to the same set of about 20 or so changing mysql servers using Mysql Workbench.  I want to keep the connections, and other configuration info synchronized between all employees.  How can I share that info, say using dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

MySQLWorkbench keeps that information in

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\connections.xml
```

If you sync that file, it should do the trick. You might want to link it to your Dropbox folder like:

```
cd  %APPDATA%\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
mklink /j connections.xml %YOUR_DROPBOX_FOLDER%\connections.xml
```